# mongodb authorization errors despite access control not being enabled

Tags: mongodb

When I login to the shell, I see:

```
Access control is not enabled for the database....
Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted...
You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
```

And within the shell, it lets me execute any command. However, when I try running a node app (using the same host & port), it tells me I'm "not authorized on test to execute command..."

I've even tried creating a root user and adding the user & password to the URI string in my app, but still no luck. The same behavior is true for any database I create.

This all makes very little sense. Any ideas?

(I'm trying to do this on Windows Subsystem for Linux, but I've also tried it with a regular Windows install of MongoDB and the result is the same)

Comment: Please don't repost questions. You can make changes to your existing question to update any details and this will even affect it's order of appearance on this site due to recent activity.

Comment: Sorry - I'm at a loss on where to go and none of the suggestions have helped